# Cannot connect to internet with ubuntu 11.10 wired connection

Tags: networking, connection, internet-connection

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Dell Optiplex 745 today. I could not connect to the internet with the LiveCD, but I installed it anyway. It still doesn't work. This is the first time linux has been installed on this computer. Windows XP connects with no problem.

I have a Broadcom NetXtreme 57xx Gigabit Controller.

I have tried removing NetworkManager and using dhclient but it doesn't work either.

I also tried:

`modprobe tg3`

and then:

`dhclient eth0`

The last command runs forever. I dont know if thats good or bad. When I do:

`ping google.com`

or try to open a page with firefox, I get a connection error.

EDIT:

`lspci` output:

```
flyingfisch@Office-OptiPlex-745:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82Q963/Q965 Memory Controller Hub (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82Q963/Q965 PCI Express Root Port (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82Q963/Q965 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 82Q963/Q965 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1a.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 02)
00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev f2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801HB/HR (ICH8/R) LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 02)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5754 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
```

EDIT2:

I don't know, maybe I am not running tg3 correctly?

When i run `modprobe tg3`, it does not run forever. It just finishes with no output. Like this:

```
# modprobe tg3
# _
```

`dhclient` loops forever though. Is that OK?

EDIT:

I booted the Ubuntu 12.04 LiveCD and it still cannot connect to the internet. I did `modprobe tg3` and it didn't seem to do anything. What should I do?

EDIT:

I got a new NIC and now it works :)

Comment: Post you lspci output

Comment: @TrailRider: ethernet.

Comment: @flyingfisch, open up a terminal, and type: lspci, put here the output given

TrailRider better? :)

Comment: edited my post to show the lspci output

Comment: Anymore help on this?

Comment: Have you tried the Broadcom driver?

Comment: @Mitch: Yes. I have tried the tg3 driver as i said in my post

Comment: I am downloading ubuntu 12.04 right now, will post if it fixes the problem.

Comment: how are your downloading, on another computer on the same network?  Does the live cd work on that *other* computer?  If the live cd works on one computer but not the other (same network) maybe it's a hardware problem.  switch ethernet cable, port, etc..?  maybe even switch NIC.  **switch the NIC**

Answer (score 0):

`dhclient` is responsible for DHCP. Since, it runs forever, you couldn't get an IP address; hence, no connection.

For more information, use `man dhclient`.

Since, the problem is now resolved, there could be some problem in you NIC or the configuration of your old NIC.